# Is Redshift/S3 Data co-mingled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift, isolation

I am working on moving our business needs into the cloud, namely using AWS Simple Storage Service and Amazon Redshift.  Because we are working with sensitive data we have some client concerns to consider.  One question we will have to answer is whether or not the data in S3/Redshift is co-mingled with other data and show evidence that it is isolated.

While researching I found information about EC2 instances being shared on the same server unless the instance is specified as a dedicated instance.  However, I been totally unable to find anything similar regarding other AWS services.  Is the data in S3 and Redshift co-mingled as well?

Comment: It can be commingled but its not possible until and unless you provide access for your redshift to access you data in s3.Imagine s3 as a schema and which cannot be read by redshift until there is a role in redshift that has permissions to read the data in s3. Generally,there are options of vpc,permissons,roles etc.. which makes your data virtually isolated.After all this is what aws gets the money for :)

Answer (score 0):

Everything on cloud is co-mingled but with security boundaries unless you pay more to get dedicated service (like dedicated EC2 hosts) in which case you should stick with on-prem.

Your concerns of co-mingling falls under `Shared Responsiblity Model` where AWS is responsible to make sure your data is not accessible by other services running on their hosts unless you open up the access.

Read this article on how `Shared Responsibility Model` works

https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/shared-responsibility-model/

Or this whitepaper

https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Security/AWS_Security_Best_Practices.pdf